# GN: Is there a way to check if geometry intersects with its neighboring geometry?

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

When adding a new piece of geometry to a collection of other pieces, is there a way to check whether the new piece intersects with its neighboring pieces?

As a simple example, the following could be a starting point: Randomizing the rotation of an extruded icosphere may or may not result in it intersecting with the one next to it. If it does intersect, it should give Boolean `TRUE`. This could, for example, trigger a **Switch** node to scale the geometry down or randomize its rotation or location again, in an attempt to prevent intersection. It could trigger a placement "retry", in a sense.

[image: How to use Geometry Nodes to check for mesh intersection, and do something?]

I've been trying to use **Mesh Boolean** in conjunction with **Attribute Statistic** to check for intersection, but have not had success yet. My logic is to ask "Is our vert count different? If so, that means we were close enough that Boolean worked, and therefore we were too close. Let's scale down and check again."

[[image] gn_mesh_intersection_check_starter.blend (Blender v3.2.1)](https://blend-exchange.com/b/QpNM9Km4/)

Comment: i had a bit to laugh for your "simple" example...because i think it is not simple. Simple would be (for me) to start with non-intersecting spheres. The first problem of boolean mesh is: it is not stable and slow (i had a conversation with developers about that).But i am very curious about solutions here....

Comment: @Chris I see what you mean. I first had rotation in mind, so I started with something that would collide with another like shape given some rotation vectors, but not others. For spheres, *location* or *scale* would need to be randomized instead of *rotation* - unless we're talking about very chunky low-poly "spheres". :-) Anyway, consider the use case of a tree, where you don't want any new branches to spawn with a loc/rot/scale that would cause them to intersect with existing branches... this example is at least simpler than that. I've added a .blend now, so no need to model anything.

Comment: I understand your problem and I wish there would be an easy and performant solution for that, but all solutions I know I kind of „poisson disk“ with min distance and „clever“ or manual rotating - so I hope for the genius GN people like Quellenform, Gorgious or Robin…maybe they know and share a way 

Comment: @Chris Yeah, maybe this is a question for the "GNiuses". ;-) Regarding Boolean operations, they have always been a bit unstable and slow since long before GN existed. But they've actually been improved on noticeably in recent releases. If there's a more lightweight way to check for intersection than Boolean in this case, I welcome it. It's not a situation requiring especially high accuracy - but higher accuracy than simple bounding boxes. A custom low-poly "collision mesh" approach could even be a consideration.

Comment: @Chris I'm very sorry to disappoint you, but I honestly don't have any better ideas than you in this case. I don't know of any node, except `Mesh Boolean`, that could detect an intersection in any way. But the bigger problem is that in case of an intersection there can be no repetition, because there are no loops. So you see, I am unfortunately only a part-time genius ;-) The only possibility I see is to choose the "right" rotation from the beginning, which can possibly be found out mathematically or by logic. But for this we would have to analyze this individual situation more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the intersection of the meshes as follows, if you really want to use the node `Mesh Boolean`:

[image]

This will give you back the result you want, but unfortunately only once.

The bigger problem I see here is that there are no loops available to repeat the mechanism until there is reliably no more intersection.

You would therefore have to repeat this manually a certain number of times.

[image]

Comment: maybe i am too dumb...but i think this won't work because you just ask the first mesh, whether it intersects, if it does, you are taking the 2nd one? and who says that the second one does not intersect? e.g. choose 51 as integer -> result gives intersection

Comment: @Chris No, you have recognized this completely correctly: Here it is checked only once whether the meshes intersect, and if so, only one other time another variant is chosen. I show here only a part of the solution, namely the part which is basically about detecting whether the meshes intersect. Unfortunately, we don't have a loop node, so any further check would have to be implemented manually...

Comment: ah ok....then i am not too dump....gladly ;)

Comment: @Chris Of course not! ...you're one of the most rock-solid *Geometry Nodes* pros I know ;-)

Comment: I suppose to improve your chances, you could create dozens variously-rotated instances simultaneously, and eliminate all but the first not to intersect.. but that's pretty filthy

Comment: **Domain Size**... I see! So if an intersection Boolean succeeds, it creates a mesh having greater than `0` verts, and intersection is `True`. Good to know how to do this. Thank you for this answer, quellenform. I'm experimenting to see if I can iterate the process.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the solution introduced in [the accepted answer by quellenform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269717/2952), I've put together an example of how intersection check logic can be iterated.

I am using a different kind of geometry for this example - a cactus-like shape that tries out random rotations with each step that it "grows". Its linear progression will hopefully make it easy to understand. This node setup ensures the next set of branches added won't collide with existing geometry.

[image]

Node tree overview:

[image: Node tree overview]

The Random Seed value can be set at each iteration. If an intersection occurs, no geometry is joined in that iteration (it skips to the next), and the height does not increment a step either.

The cap added to the top at the end is not super important to the concept, but it does get its position from the height that results from the Step counter.

Memory may become an issue on very detailed meshes because the intersection check is always performed against the summed mix of all the joined geometry. Since this particular example only grows vertically, the setup could be modified to check against only the previously added "piece" of geometry, and this would most likely improve performance, but depending on the shape might result in intersections. This setup is more "strict", you might say.

Inside the "Growth Iteration" Group Node:

[image: Inside the "Growth Iteration" Group Node]

Inside the "Random Rotation" Group Node:

[image: Inside the "Random Rotation" Group Node]

To match the octagonal topology of this mesh, the Turn Steps are set to 8.

The vertical Translation of the mesh (see the Frame labeled "Move up 1 increment") is a value of `1` because the "trunk" of this mesh was made to be exactly 1.00 Blender Unit high. This can easily be adjusted by multiplying 1 against some other value (Step for the cap's Transform node would need to be multiplied by the same value).

With these considerations in mind, the *rotation* and the *translation* (distance and direction) are variables one would likely want to customize to fit the source geometry.

Inside the "Check Intersection" Group Node:

[image: Inside the "Check Intersection" Group Node]

With a setup like this, a lot of the node architecture is reliant on the geometry, so the nodes will need to be modified if the geometry is changed. But hopefully this example illustrates the concept well enough, and customization shouldn't be too complicated.

[[image] gn_geometry_intersection_check_iterative.blend (Blender v3.2.1)](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vG9eqAO8/)

<sub>P.S. If you find this answer useful, please consider giving quellenform's answer an upvote too. :-)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for expanding on my little example, and thanks for the credits! I think we are really starting to need a loop node ;-)

Comment: @quellenform Sure, no worries! Yeah, a loop node would be great! Haha